# Ergodicity and equidistribution

Tags: ergodic-theory, chaos-theory

It is known that ergodicity imply dense, but *not* vice-versa.
Also dense *does not* imply equidistribution ([example](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EquidistributedSequence.html)). But what about
equidistribution and ergodicity properties?

Comment: Since ergodicity is usually defined for a [measure preserving system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure-preserving_dynamical_system), whereas density and equidistribution are defined for countable sequences of reals, would you please define what it means for a sequence to be ergodic? Or explain what exactly is meant by 'ergodicity implies dense, but not vice-versa'?

Comment: We may use symbolic dynamics methods [like here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_scheme) and Poincaré map for converting orbits of dynamical system into sequences of reals or even integers.

Comment: But what about vice-versa? What would it mean for density to imply ergodicity? Are we given a dense sequence and asked to construct an ergodic measure preserving system for which it represents the orbits?

Comment: [link](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/74279/example-of-a-measure-preserving-system-with-dense-orbits-that-is-not-ergodic)

Comment: But I much more interested about equidistribution...

Comment: Now I understand your question; it's a good one. More people might respond if you ask it more clearly and precisely though.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try recently.